# DRF / POST view for two tables connected by foreign keys

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to write POST view for two tables that are mapped by foreignkey?

here are my models..

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True, 
                               editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    enable = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class PostImages(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

serializer:

```
class UserPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['author','title','description']
```

I made view but it doesn't do anything with PostImages table..
I want it to create post with images..

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def PostUpload(request):
    data = request.data
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserPostSerializer(data=data, many=False)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(author=user)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
class PostImagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostImages
        fields = ['images']

class UserPostSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
   post_set = PostImagesSerializer()
   class Meta:
       model = Post
       fields = ['author','title','description', 'post_set']
```

1. Suffix _set allows you to refer to the FK (or you can just add 'related_name' to FK)
2. Avoid variable names like "post", "get" etc.
3. You can use breakpoint() or shell and use `dir()` to see the methods available for your model (there should be `post_set` or `postimages_set` I don't remember)
4. Now you can refer in the view to PostImages
5. Read about https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested

Comment: oh it works thanks! I understand the concept of nested serializer now.